# SP2010 User Profile Service - Incremental Sync not working

Tags: 2010, user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync

we have a sharepoint 2010 fram with 2 WFE and 2 App Server. On one App Service we have activated the user priovile Service and user provile syncronisation service. If i start a full syncronisation, all AD updates will be imported and with the Sp synced. But if i start e incremental syncronisation no AD changes will be imported in SP. If i check we Forefront Identity Manager Log, the AD Changes were importet (DS_DELTAIMPORT Profile) but not sync. (MOSS_DELTASYNC). Knows every Body this problem and can help me ..?

Comment: Use the FIM client tool during User Profile sync this can be useful for viewing progress and identifying errors. 
The FIM Client is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Answer (score 1):

Recheck that your synchronization account, the one entered in the Sync Connection, has Replicating Directory Changes on the OU that you are synchronizing from per this article: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx